# How to group existing multiple canvas textures?

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, phaser-framework, group

I have created 3 canvas texture in file a.ts:

```
    this.textures1 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures1', 450, 170)
    this.textures2 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures2', 410, 180)
    this.textures3 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures3', 400, 210)
```

and in file b.ts I want to create a group multiple canvas texture to use function `overlap(groupCanvas, object)`.

I can call 3 canvas texture in file b.ts by using: `this.textures.get('canvastextures1')`

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `this.textures.createCanvas` just creates a normal texture, so you can simply create gameobjects *(like phaser-images)* and add them to a group *(or physics group)*, than you can check for overlap, between a gameobject and the *texture*-group.

***Updated* full example:**

```js
// Minor formating for stackoverflow
document.body.style = "display: flex;flex-direction: column;";    


class FirstScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super('firstScene')
  }
  
  create(){
    this.add.rectangle(0,0, 600,20, 0xff0000).setOrigin(0)
    this.scene.start('secondScene')
  }
  
  createTextures(){
      let helperGraphics = this.make.graphics({x:0, y: 0, add: false});
      helperGraphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
      helperGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20 );
      helperGraphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
      helperGraphics.fillRect(20, 0, 20, 20 );
      helperGraphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
      helperGraphics.fillRect(40, 0, 20, 20 );
      helperGraphics.generateTexture('helper', 60, 20);
      let img = this.textures.get('helper').getSourceImage()
    
      this.textures1 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures1', 20, 20)
      this.textures1.draw(-40, 0, img)
      
      this.textures2 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures2', 20, 20)
      this.textures2.draw(-20, 0, img)
      
      this.textures3 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures3',20, 20)
      this.textures3.draw(0, 0, img)
      
      this.textures4 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures4',40, 40)
      this.textures4.draw(20, 10, this.textures.get('canvastextures2').getSourceImage())
      this.textures4.draw(10, 0, this.textures.get('canvastextures1').getSourceImage())
      
      this.textures4.draw(0, 10, this.textures.get('canvastextures3').getSourceImage())   
  }
}

class SecondScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super('secondScene')
  }
  
  create(){
    this.textureGroup = this.physics.add.group({
        immovable: true,
        allowGravity: false
    });           
    
    let loadScene = this.scene.get('firstScene')
    
    loadScene.createTextures();
    
    this.textureGroup = this.physics.add.group({
        immovable: true,
        allowGravity: false
    });  
    
    this.textureGroup.add(
        this.add.image(100, 25, 'canvastextures1').setOrigin(0)
    )
    
    this.textureGroup.add(
        this.add.image(100, 75, 'canvastextures2').setOrigin(0)
    )
    
    this.textureGroup.add(
        this.add.image(100, 125, 'canvastextures3').setOrigin(0)
    )
    
    this.ball = this.add.rectangle(100, 0, 10, 10, 0xffffff)  
    this.physics.add.existing(this.ball)
    
    this.add.text(200, 30, 'Alternative:\nmerged all textures,\nin a new texture', { fontSize:10, color: '#ffffff', align: 'center' }).setOrigin(.5, 0)
    this.add.image(200, 75, 'canvastextures4').setOrigin(.5, 0)
            
    this.physics.add.overlap(this.ball, this.textureGroup, overlap )
  }
}

function overlap(player, groupItem){
    groupItem.setTint(0xcdcdcd)
    setTimeout(_ => groupItem.clearTint() , 400)
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics:{
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade:{ gravity:{y: 100}}
    },
    scene: [FirstScene, SecondScene],
    banner: false
}; 

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js">
</script>
```

***Extra:** If you want to create **a new texture** from three seperate textures, checkout `textures4`.*

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but in file a.ts I have created 3 image object for 3 canvas texture like this:
```
this.textures1 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures1', 450, 170)
this.land1 = this.textures.get(MAPOPTIONS.BASE1_NAME).getSourceImage()
this.textures1.draw(0, 0, this.land1)
this.textures1.context.globalCompositeOperation
```
In file b.ts, how can I group these image object?

Comment: @CSNo.1 Maybe I misunderstand, but I answered this, point. create a group with ` this.physics.add.group` and add the gameobjects to the group `this.textureGroup.add`, but I will add a code snipplet

Comment: @CSNo.1 I update my answer I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, winner_joiner, but I have called `this.add.image()` in another file to create Sprite object, but I donnot want to group these Sprite object, only the canvas texture. What is the parameter of `this.textureGroup.add()`?

Comment: @CSNo.1 the code above should show how it works, I changed it(it simulates two files with the two difference scenes). but in any case `this.textureGroup` is a `physics-group` https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group.html. I hope this helps

Comment: the parameter of `this.textureGroup.add()` can by any __gameobject__ https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group.html#add__anchor